# Best way to stop multiple RT Timed Loops simultaneously?

Tags: while-loop, real-time, labview, fifo

#### Background

I have a real-time application, `RT Main`, that has multiple high-priority timed loops running some simulation code and using RT FIFOs to communicate with a low-priority communication loop that talks with an outside program. I also have a monitoring VI, `DT Main`, running on a non-real-time desktop that I use to start and stop the real-time simulation, load parameter files, that sort of thing.

Currently I am passing the `Stop` button from `DT Main` to `RT Main` via a network shared variable. What I want to know is: how can I use this to stop all of my loops on `RT Main` at (close to) the same time?

I know I could use a FIFO-enabled network shared variable in my Timed Loops, but I am worried that with multiple loops reading from the same FIFO, I would only stop one or two of them and then the FIFO would be cleared and the other loops would not stop.

#### Current Plan

1. Stop the low-priority communication loop using the network shared `Stop` button variable.
2. Delete all of my RT FIFOs when this loop stops using the [`RT FIFO Delete`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370622K-01/lvrtvihelp/rtfifodelete/) VI with the `force destroy?` input set to `True`.
3. Let the high-priority loops shut themselves down the next time they try to read their (now destroyed) FIFOs, which will hopefully cause an error.

This is illustrated in a distilled example below.

[image: Illustrative Example VI]

#### Questions

I have two questions: will this work? And regardless of whether this works, **what is the "right" way to stop multiple high-priority Timed Loops in a real-time application in LabVIEW?**

I can't figure out whether the [`RT FIFO Read`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370622K-01/lvrtvihelp/rtfiforead/) and [`RT FIFO Write`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370622K-01/lvrtvihelp/rtfifowrite/) VIs will throw an error if they try to read/write from/to a FIFO that isn't there. There is an [RT FIFO error code -2206 "RT FIFO does not exist"](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370622K-01/lvrthelp/rtfifo_error_codes/) that I would assume gets thrown in these cases, but I cannot test it right now (no hardware to run this on yet) and so I cannot verify.

For the record, I have found the [NI LabVIEW for CompactRIO Developer's Guide](http://www.ni.com/pdf/products/us/fullcriodevguide.pdf) pretty helpful so far, but it does not seem to get into enough detail to answer my question.

Thanks!

#### Update

I was able to test the code and verify that I can stop multiple Timed Loops in this way, but I would still be interested in hearing what your *best* method is for shutting down a remote RT VI with multiple loops at the press of a button on your desktop VI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code works for shutting down multiple Timed Loops simultaneously using errors from the destroyed FIFOs. I was able to verify it with the VI shown below.

[image: Example VI Front Panel]

[image: Example VI Block Diagram]

I would still be interested in hearing your *best* solution for stopping an RT VI with multiple loops from a single stop button on your desktop VI.

Answer (score 2):

The concern with timed loops is keeping everything deterministic.

The other option for deterministic comms you have is using shared variables with RT FIFO enabled. If you set this to be a single element FIFO it still works like a normal variable.

I believe this can directly be a network variable as well without any problems, or sometimes I like to keep internal comms internal and have another loop that will read the network variable and write it to the internal variable to reduce coupling between the host and RT target implementation.

This allows for a more explicit stop function in the software which increases flexibility and readability as well. See the image for an example:

[image: stopping rt loops]

Comment: Thanks! I have a concern with this, but I may just be misunderstanding something. Every time one of the loops reads from the FIFO-enabled shared variable, it removes the oldest element from that variable, correct? So would I need to continuously write a `True` value to the `Stop` shared variable so that all the loops that share it have a chance to read it? I feel like I have had some issues synching loops with shared variables in the past, but I may not have been enabling FIFO.

Comment: Also, I already have the FIFOs. I do like having something a bit more explicit stopping the loops though, so that somebody maintaining the code down the line isn't confused about the magical shutdown procedure.

Comment: When the RT FIFO settings of the shared variable are set to single element it no longer works like a FIFO but like a variable so you can write once and every place reads this.

As you say, you already have the FIFOs so this is extra but it is more explicit so I tend to prefer it for that reason, but functionally both can work.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be the best way to do this and is a cross-platform [Producer-Consumer pattern](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3023/en/).  One suggestion I have is *do not* use the `Force Destroy` option when destroying the FIFOs.  It would be best to keep track of the FIFOs individually and make sure you are destroying all instances properly rather than just atomically eliminating all references to the FIFO.  From what I can see in your application, you are not creating named FIFOs, so there should be no need to atomically destroy all instances of the FIFO.

Cheers, Matt

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I am in fact creating named FIFOs in the actual application. I just didn't think it was too important for the illustrative example. In light of named FIFOs, is the `force destroy?` option still my best bet?

Comment: This should be sufficient as long as your loops clean up as necessary when the FIFO access fails.